# linux - cronjob with sed return error

Tags: linux, sed, cron

I generate a custom script using php and then every minutes I call it.

it is something like:

```
grep -rl 'text1' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/text1/text'"$1"'/g'
```

when I run it as root (manually) it works great but when run via crontab I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command
./b.sh: 5: ./b.sh: [[: not found
```

how fix it?

Comment: Run the script with `env -i ./b.sh` to more closely model crontab's environment. It sounds like you're at least missing a shebang

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks! I find problem with that

Answer (score 1):

First Time... so hi

This error 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated`s' command`
Implies that "s" is containing special characters that cause sed to interpret the command differently.

This is due to bash inserting the variable as part of the command which gets passed to sed and if it has any special characters it changes the output. Im guessing "s" is something to do with an environment variable due to it working fine manually but not in crontab.

Im not familiar with sed, but you may need to escape your $FOO variables by preceding it with a backslash \ and if this doesn't work, awk may be needed.

See the reference for an example of how to use sed/awk.

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75310/why-is-sed-giving-me-an-error-about-an-unterminated-s